# How to cancel request in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a **searchBar** in my Xamarin app.
And I am making an API call with the search terms after each character is entered by the user.

But my issue here is **sometimes the response for the string with the 3rd(LOV) character comes before the response of the 2nd (LO).**

So my question here is how to cancel the previous request (LO) while making a new API call (LOV).

```
public async Task<Search> GetProgrammingSearchAsync(string searchString)
{
    var search = new SearchAllModel();

    var encodedsearchstring = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("\"{0}\"", searchString));
    encodedsearchstring = encodedsearchstring.Replace("+", "%20");

    string token = await GetToken();
    if (token != null)
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT", (string)token);

    var query = "search/" + encodedsearchstring;

    var uri = new Uri(Path.Combine(Settings.RestUrl, query));
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (IsSuccess(response))
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            search = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchAllModel>(content, new SearchModelConverter());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return search;
}
```

I have searched over the internet and couldn't find any potential solution to try hence can't share any code.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to make an "API request".  Without knowing specifically what you're doing there's no way we can tell you how to cancel it.  Please post the relevant code you are using to make the request.

Comment: Ok sure I will post my code here!

Comment: What you are looking for is called cancellationtokensource. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099265/async-task-cancellation-c-sharp-xamarin) may help.

Comment: @Jason I have added the code.

Comment: see the answer in the linked duplicate