# Request data after short delay when character is typed in Entry control with Xamarin Forms and MVVM

Tags: .net, xamarin, mvvm, timer, prism

I'm trying to request data when characters are typed in an Entry control in Xamarin Forms but I need to request it after a short delay has occurred (i.e. 500ms for example) so that if a user types more characters, I don't want to request it for each character typed.

The timer should be reset/cancelled whenever a character is typed and only when the full delay (i.e. not character typed) is reached, 500ms, I want to request data via my web api and fill a listview.

I've got the following code that I found while googling and I thought I'd give it a shot but I'm not surprised I'm getting reflection errors as a) It looks more like something I'd call from a windows based app and b) I wouldn't call it from a property but I'm just not sure how to go about it.

```
private void RequestData(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Delay(500, _cancellationTokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(async t =>
        {
            await GetData(
                this._pageIndex,
                this._pageSize,
                this._orderBy,
                this._orderByDirection,
                searchText);

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, When I call the above method from a property (binded to the entry control), I'm getting a few reflection errors.

Is there a better method to implement this keeping in mind that I'm using the MVVM pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099265/async-task-cancellation-c-sharp-xamarin) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it something like this

```
        private Task FetchTask = null;
        private string searchText = null;
        private bool searchStringChanged;

        public string SearchText {
            get { return searchText; }
            set
            {
                searchText = value;
                searchStringChanged = true;
                if (FetchTask == null)
                {
                    FetchTask = RequestData(searchText);
                }
                else if(FetchTask.IsCompleted || FetchTask.IsCanceled || FetchTask.IsFaulted)
                {
                    FetchTask = RequestData(searchText);
                }

            }
        }

        private async Task RequestData(string searchString)
        {
            while(searchStringChanged)
            {
                searchStringChanged = false;
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
            FetchTask = null;

            await GetData(
                this._pageIndex,
                this._pageSize,
                this._orderBy,
                this._orderByDirection,
                searchText);
        }
```

Comment: Isn't what you have suggested cause a 500ms delay to occur between each key being pressed?

Comment: No...It cause 500ms delay in get data after LAST key stroke. If there is no new key stroke for 500 ms, then it will call GetData.

Comment: Assuming your goal is to reduce network call between key strokes, the ideal delay should be around 2.5 ~ 3 seconds.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested in your solution but it doesn't work correctly. When I type characters quickly, it only picks up the first one. If I type slowly, it works. I've found another solution elsewhere so I will give that one a shot and post an update if I get it to work.

Comment: I've posted an answer which I got working for me but thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question by spending more time googling it and I found the following articles which provide pretty much the same code:

1. [Xamarin: Search As You Type with Delay (by Ian Vink)](https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2018/08/24/xamarin-search-as-you-type-with-delay/)
2. [How to delay UISearchBar.TextChanged event? (by James Lavery)](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69118/how-to-delay-uisearchbar-textchanged-event)

In my case, I just adjusted a bit as I needed to call this from my viewmodel in a property binded to the Text property:

```
public string SearchText
{
    get => this._searchText;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref this._searchText, value);
        DelayedQueryForKeyboardTypingSearches(this._searchText);
    }
}

private async void DelayedQueryForKeyboardTypingSearches(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this._cancellationTokenSource, 
             new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 
              this._cancellationTokenSource.Token)
            .ContinueWith(async task => await FetchData(searchText, true),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    catch
    {
        //Ignore any Threading errors
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm still using `Async` but I've had to change the method to `void` rather `Task` as I couldn't have an await in my SearchText property.

It works a charm but note that I've only tested this with Android as I'm concentrating on this OS first, then I'll deal with iOS when I've got this one finished. Hopefully it will work the same way in both.