# CancellationToken Source not working in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have 5 Task running together.

```
        var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        Task<InvServiceModel> t1 = GetInventoryLine(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(t1);

        Task<ProductServiceModel> t2 = GetProductData(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(t2);

        Task<List<InvLineCost>> t3 = GetInvLineCostData(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(t3);

        Task<MiscDataMobileServiceModel> t4 = GetMiscellaniousMobileData(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(t4);

        Task<RecipeHierarchyModel> t5 = GetRecipeHierarhyData(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(t5);

        Task<UnknownInvStorage> t6 = GetUnknownStorageLocationData(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        tasks.Add(t6);


        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            if (ae.InnerExceptions.Any(e => e is TaskCanceledException))
                Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled exception detected");
            else
                throw;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ae)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled exception detected {0}", ae);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        }
```

Now when my internet goes off i cancel the token source:

```
    public override async void InternetConnectivityChanged(bool IsConnected)
    {
        if (!AppsContext.Instance.IsErrorMessagePopupDisplayed && IsMasterDataUpdating)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        base.InternetConnectivityChanged(IsConnected);
    }
```

How to cancel all the Tasks ? There seems to be some kind of issue as

```
 cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

is not getting called in the Individual Task methods.

Sample service call Method as below:

```
    public async Task<InvServiceModel> GetInventoryLineItems(string Restaurantid, string 
      FromDate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        InvServiceModel invservicemodel = null;
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;

        try
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var api = RestService.For<IInventoryLineItemsApi>(_httpClient);
            responseMessage = await api.GetInventoryLineItems(Restaurantid, FromDate, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
               //
            }
            else
            {
                //
                throw serviceException;
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException GetInventoryLineItems");
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return invservicemodel;
    }
```

Comment: You need to hold a reference to it, so that the next time the handler is invoked, the previous search can be cancelled .Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099265/async-task-cancellation-c-sharp-xamarin .